# Remove Mice Smell from Car AC Unit

Tags: car, smell

Earlier this week we discovered our car (Honda CRV 2019) had a mouse nest above the AC filter. I removed the dead mice and the nest, however, we assumed nothing had fallen into the Air Blower itself (below the AC Filter). A dead mouse remained inside it until I removed it.

We're now attempting to get rid of the smell of the nest and dead mice. What's the best way to get rid of the smell in the AC Unit / Car?

Answer (score 2):

Try with an ozone generator and let the AC unit run during ozone production. Don't be in the room ozone is harmful.

Ozone will oxidize many compounds, therefore reducing the smell. When you enrich the environment with ozone and let the AC run during that time air will pass through the passages where the mouse had its nest therefore reducing the smell.

Comment: It’s built in a car, not a free-standing domestic unit. How should the asker combine this with the ozone generator? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Stephie Tried to clarify it..

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I still don’t get how you suggest the AC unit *in the car* gets in contact with the ozone. Would you have to run the car in an enclosed garage? Run the engine? Modern cars shut off their electric components to save energy, so would the asker have to restart it every twenty to thirty minutes? Just curious, because ozone sounds like a good idea.

Comment: https://www.wikihow.com/Do-an-Ozone-Shock-Treatment-on-a-Vehicle .  This is similar to how some car detailing operations remove stubborn odours.  You can run the cabin fan from the car battery for a while (turn the key part way between off and run, or press start without putting your foot on the brake) but you’ll eventually kill the battery. Probably best to leave the engine running while the cabin fan is running. Periodic restarts should not be necessary but YMMV. Don’t ever run your car engine in an a closed space.

Comment: I'm not a mechanic but from hearsay I know that professionals do It that way, for example if the former owner was a smoker. Yes run the ozone generator in a garage. I don't know if modern cars shutdown electric components after a while. If that is the case install some duct fan as such that it sucks air through the ac. (just make some temporary installment using strong duct tape (panzer tape) I guess you could also suck it in the reverse direction i.e. from inside the car to the engine bonnet, if you want to avoid sticking duct tape to the interior of your car..power duct fan over power supply

Comment: Also, I should add that leaving a running car unattended is a bad idea, and in fact illegal in my city (car theft capital of Canada).

Comment: Change the filter too. In my car it is a wad of folded paper.